# CSS - ::after has another padding in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, pseudo-element

I have a button (tag `a`) with pseudo element ::after. The problem is that element after looks different in chrome and in firefox

Google Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Mozilla Firefox:

[image]

My code is:

```
<a class="play_button" href="#">Some link</a>


a.play_button {
    background-color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #49bf96;
    position: relative;
    padding: 6px 23px 7px 23px;
    border: solid 1px #49bf96;
    top: 30px;
    right: 12px;
}
a.play_button::after {
    background-color: white;
    content: url('http://elvis.zitnikcreative.cz/wp-content/themes/elvis_theme/img/darovat_vystoupeni_sipka.png');
    width: 10px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 9px;
    top: -1px;
    right: -28px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #49bf96;
    border: solid 1px #49bf96;
    border-left: solid 1px #49bf96;
}
a.play_button:hover {
    background-color: #49bf96;
    color: white;
    border: solid 1px #1c7d5c;
}
a.play_button:hover::after {
    content: url('http://elvis.zitnikcreative.cz/wp-content/themes/elvis_theme/img/bila_sipka.png');
    background-color: #49bf96;
    color: white;
    border: solid 1px #1c7d5c;
    border-left: solid 1px #1c7d5c;
}
```

[**JSFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xn8wcgdp/1/)

How can I fix it? The answer in JSFiddle would be best.

Comment: What do you suspect might be causing this problem? Same in Safari btw.

Comment: I don't know, that's why I'm asking here. Maybe padding or height of after element

Comment: I made a fiddle with height 100% but the image is not centered http://jsfiddle.net/xn8wcgdp/12/

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/xn8wcgdp/15/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few fixes required in your code.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/xn8wcgdp/15/)**

---

So, first off, you were using the `top:` and `right:` declarations on a relatively positioned element, which isn't really required/redundant.

You were using padding/margins on the pseudo element, which isn't really a great idea. This also included the likes of 'reusing' the px height instead of 100% of parent.

There were other minor alterations, although these as I said were minor.

```css
a.play_button {
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #49bf96;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px 23px 7px 23px;
  border: solid 1px #49bf96;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}
a.play_button::after {
  background-color: white;
  content: url('http://elvis.zitnikcreative.cz/wp-content/themes/elvis_theme/img/darovat_vystoupeni_sipka.png');
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #49bf96;
  border: solid 1px #49bf96;
  border-left: solid 1px #49bf96;
}
a.play_button:hover {
  background-color: #49bf96;
  color: white;
  border: solid 1px #1c7d5c;
}
a.play_button:hover::after {
  content: url('http://elvis.zitnikcreative.cz/wp-content/themes/elvis_theme/img/bila_sipka.png');
  background-color: #49bf96;
  color: white;
  border: solid 1px #1c7d5c;
  border-left: solid 1px #1c7d5c;
}
```

```html
<a class="play_button" href="#">Some link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `width: auto; height: auto;` to `.play_button`.

```
a.play_button {
    background-color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #49bf96;
    position: relative;
    padding: 7px 23px;
    border: solid 1px #49bf96;
    width: auto; height: auto;
    top: 30px;
    right: 12px;
}
```

And I modified the `::after` selector like so `padding: 7px 10px;` `text-align: middle;` `top: -1px;` `right: -29px;`

**Take a look at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xn8wcgdp/11/)**

Answer (score 0):

i adjusted the font-size. but, this is not the correct implementation. I suggest you to use glyph-icons or font awesome to the chevron right icon. 
fiddle here:- [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xn8wcgdp/13/)

```
font-size: 17px;
```